# Install package from package registry instead of local when using NPM workspaces

Tags: npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, storybook, npm-workspaces

I'm working on a design system and we are moving from a simple project with all dependencies on the same build step, to a one with a more granular approach, where tokens and icons are separated packages (this allow us to move quickly if we need to add icons or change some tokens without needing to publish new library version). To do that, we started to use NPM workspaces. In general they work fine, but we are having issues with dependencies present on the same repo.

The structure of the project is something like this:

```
- root
  - icons
    - icons-folder
    package.json
  - tokens
    - tokens.json
    package.json
  - library
    package.json
  package.json
```

`Icons` and `tokens` are dependencies on `library`. When I run `npm ci` looks like it's installing the "local" version of the packages prior to the build step, so there are some files not present yet. For instance we are using **Style Dictionary** to build tokens to css, scss and js files, but the tokens definition is on a JSON file.

**The problem is when I try this:**

```
➜ npm ci
➜ npm run storybook:build
```

If I run this (locally oo inside Gitlab CI), I get an error because is not possible to resolve `tokens.css` on `preview.js` from storybook.

If I run `npm run tokens:build` and `npm run icons:build` prior to `npm run storybook:build` it works fine.

```
➜ npm run tokens:build
➜ npm run icons:build
➜ npm run storybook:build
```

AFAIK, the issue arises because NPM finds a `package.json` that meets package name and version declared on the `package.json` inside library and install the content of that folder, but after reading docs, I couldn't find a way to force installation from npm registry instead of the local version.

Is there a way to force installation from NPM package registry? Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious what your solution has been to solve this issue. I'm in the same situation right now, trying to figure out how to switch between local files and remote repo with npm workspaces, and not able to figure it out.

Comment: No solution yet.I solved the issue adding the build commands prior to any other.

For instance, to run Storybook, first I run `npm run tokens:build` that way I have available all the tokens generated. For sure there is a solution outside because is a common scenario to have something that needs to be compiled prior to use, TS is a good example I think.


Right now I'm doing my work and this is a "good enough" solution, but I'll update this if I found a solution.

Comment: OK, thanks. I am coming to the understanding that Workspaces always wants to reference the latest code from the filesystem for any of the projects defined in the top-level workspace package.json. Other tools may be more flexible, but NPM doesn't seem to have the tooling.